# Endless scrolling only working on 1 page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This seemingly simple problem is driving me crazy. I am following [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised) to implement endless scrolling but am only able to get it to work on my posts index page. Doing it on any other page does't work.

I'll start with the page that *does* work.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
@posts = Post.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
end
```

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
<div id="products">
<%= render 'posts/post' %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

**posts/_index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#products').append('<%= j render(@posts) %>');
<% if @posts.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@posts) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

and finally, posts.js.coffee

```
  jQuery ->
    if $('.pagination').length
      $(window).scroll ->
        url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
        if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
          $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...")
          $.getScript(url)
      $(window).scroll()
```

And now the page that *does not* work.

To start I have the same jquery in users.js.coffee.

**users_controller.rb**

```
def allusers
@users = User.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)    
end
```

**users/allusers.html.erb**

```
<div id="products">
<%= render 'users/allusers' %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @users %>
```

**users/_allusers.html.erb**

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
<%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

**users/allusers.js.erb**

```
$('#products').append('<%= j render(@users) %>');
<% if @users.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@users) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

On this page "loading more products" appears but it never actually loads more products.

Answer (score 0):

**Asset Pipeline**

The most significant problem I can see is that you're calling `erb` code with your `allusers.js.erb` file.

You don't mention where this file is stored - so I am presuming it's in the `app/assets/javascripts` directory (which means it's part of the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html))

--

The problem you have is that if you're using a file in the asset pipeline, you **cannot make it dynamic**. It has to be "static", so that it can be [precompiled](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) when you push your application to production

Specifically, when you call the following method:

```
`append('<%= j render(@users) %>');`
```

Now, looking at it properly, I'm guessing that you're actually loading this from the controller response / views area, so I'll detail how to do that here:

--

**Dynamic**

If, of course, your file is a result of calling from the `format.js` callback in your controller, things are a little different. I'll detail what I'd do here:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def index
       respond_to do |format|
          format.js #-> will call /app/views/users/index.js.erb
       end
   end
end
```

I believe your problem is that you're calling the `partial` name for the `.js.erb` file (`allusers.js.erb`). This does not work, as the `action` you're using in your controller is *not* `allusers`, but `index`

You must remember when you access a `route` for your Rails application, it will load up a controller action. This is very important, as this is completely independent to your `partials`

So what I'd recommend is to rename your `allusers.js.erb` to the action you're accessing, which I presume is **`index.js.erb`**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After reading it I thought for sure my problem was the respond_to do |format| bit in the controller. I had to add format.html as well to get it to work but it didn't actually fix the loading. Just to clarify, on this page i'm using the allusers action in the users controller so I didn't change the name of the .js.erb file which I believe is correct. Let me know if not.

Comment: I think not - what URL are you pinging with your JS?

Comment: oh okay - so you have a method called `allusers`?

Comment: Yep, in the users controller.